# SQL query optimiser for (ISNULL(@parameter) OR @parameter > Column) patterns and whether it optimises for when @parameter is null

Tags: sql, performance, prepared-statement, query-optimization, rdbms

If I had a form where the user can specify a bunch of filters (e.g. productid > 5, category = "Applicances", Price > 3), it seems natural to make a single prepared statement like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE 
  (@Price IS NULL OR Price > @Price) AND
  (@Category IS NULL OR @Category = Category) AND
  (@ProductID IS NULL OR Price > @Product);
```

Then add the @Price, @Category and @ProductID as parameters, which are null when the User hasn't inputted anything into the form.

However, is the Query Optimiser clever enough for when @Category and @ProductID is null, to only use an Index for the Price? This is because you will have the condition `(ISNULL(NULL) OR NULL = Category)`, which is always going to be true. E.g. does it do exactly the same thing as if:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE Price > @Price
```

had been prepared?

Does it depend on which SQL engine is used? (SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, Postgres)

Comment: "*Does it depend on which SQL engine is used*" - yes absolutely.

Comment: `ISNULL(@Price)` is MySQL specific, it should be rather `@Price IS NULL`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda is there a more generic way of giving that function? Whatever the sql engine uses for null equality, question isn't mysql specific.

Comment: @Nick Yes, as I posted `@var IS NULL`

Comment: In order to get an optimal plan based on which parameters are provided you need to either (1) build your where clause dynamically and execute a prepared statement or (b) force recomplilation of the query with each execution. Given how different this is across DMBS I doubt you find a single resources that answers this for all DBMS. To give an idea of how difficult (and long) this would be, see how much Erland Sommarskog managed to write for just T-SQL: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the Query Optimiser clever enough for when @Category and @ProductID is null, to only use an Index for the Price?

Generally, combinations of `and` and `or` on multiple columns message up index usage.  In some databases, it is possible to use multiple indexes for a single `where` clause.

However, it might be better to construct the query as dynamic SQL.  Something like this in SQL Server (which is most similar to the code you have provided):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT * 
FROM Products
WHERE 1=1';

IF (@Price IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' Price > @Price'
END;

. . .
```

You can then pass the parameters in using `sp_executesql`.

Essentially, the code creates a family of queries -- depending on the parameters -- which can then each be optimized separately.

Comment: dynamic query solves it, but it's quite alot of work unfortunately and involves alot of string munging. Was hoping the query optimiser could do my work for me!